# Keeping footer on to the bottom with 2 divs on sides and main content

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I am sorry for not beeing able to produce much code, otherwise my assignment could be detected as plagiarism. Following this tutorial I was able to create a sticky footer when having no sidebars. Trying to do the same with 2 divs -> "left-sidebar" and "right-sidebar" I got this:
[image]

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
header {
  padding: 10px;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
}
#main-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  /* Height of the footer */
}
#left-sidebar {
  width: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
#right-sidebar {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    
    <header>
    </header>
    
    <div id="left-sidebar">
    </div>
    
    <div id="main-content">
    </div>
    
    <div id="right-sidebar">
    </div>
    
    <footer>
    </footer>
    
  </div>
</body>
```

My technique is based on declaring the wrapper's position as relative, and the inside elements' as absolute. I know there is another technique when declaring the footers position relative as well, and then writing it outside of wrapper. If one could provide both solutions, I would be really happy! Thanks!

@I am exploring possibilities, so I'm trying to solve this without the "push" div

@What I actually want to achieve is this mockup
[image: MOCKUP]

And I don't wanna used fixed position for footer, because its gonna stick to the bottom of my window and not of the "page"

I just dont understand these dumb haters downvoting for nothing, at least you could comment and give a critic!

Comment: I'm confused as to what exactly you want in the end (is the footer supposed to be contained by the left/right sidebars? Are they sticky as well, or do they have a height cut off? etc). A more accurate description, or a mock up of what you are wanting in the end, would be more helpful for me. 

Either way, in the end, I would be using `position:fixed` instead of absolute on the sticky footer, it's a place to start.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I knew I'll forget something. I've uploaded the mockup and argumented your proposal :) Hope you understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve that like this:

```css
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 40px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #333;
}
header {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #333;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0px;
}
#main-content {
    width: 60%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#left-sidebar {
    width: 15%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#right-sidebar {
    width: 15%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left-sidebar"></div>
    <div id="main-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    <div id="right-sidebar"></div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: It works perfectly, I just took a bit time to wait for some other solutions(courious guy who wants to learn :P). So far you're is the most elegant, thanks :)!

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/roZhOyMUxkFmpsYr9tKW?p=preview

```css
html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 400 16px/1.5'Palatino Linotype';
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #EFE;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.shell {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1.5em .75em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 17vw;
  top: 10vh;
  outline: 3px dashed yellow;
  width: 66vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 15px;
}
header,
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  outline: 2px solid cyan;
  padding: 12px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: hsla(160, 0%, 181%, .4);
}
footer {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  bottom: 0;
}
header {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  top: 0;
}
article {
  outline: 3px dashed white;
  height: 100%;
}
section {
  width: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid lime;
  height: 20vh;
}
.left,
.right {
  outline: 2px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  width: 23vh;
  height: 80vh;
  padding: 5px;
}
.left {
  left: 0;
}
.right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="shell">
    <header>
      <h1>H1 - Header</h1>
    </header>

    <nav class="left">
      <h4>H4 - Nav</h4>
    </nav>

    <main class="content">
      <h1>H1 - Main</h1>
      <article class="blog">
        <h2>H2 - Article</h2>
        <section id="intro">
          <h3>H3 - Section - Introduction</h3>
        </section>
        <section id="part1">
          <h3>H3 - Section - Part 1</h3>
        </section>
        <section id="part2">
          <h3>H3 - Section - Part 2</h3>
        </section>
        <section id="part3">
          <h3>H3 - Section - Part 3</h3>
        </section>
      </article>

    </main>

    <aside class="right">
      <h4>H4 - Aside</h4>
    </aside>

    <footer>
      <h3>H3 - Footer</h3>
    </footer>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution.
You want the header to stay at the top of you page, the footer at the bottom, and the sidebars/content will scroll

Add this to your CSS header:

```
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 999;
```

Just change your CSS footer from 'absolute' positioning, to 'fixed' like so:

```
position: fixed;
```

Comment: Na, actually as I stated, fixed footer is not what i was looking for. But thanks anyway!